# Why is Android App greyed out when adding "Run/Debug Configurations" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I see Android App greyed out. I am trying to select it to run my app now that I have an emulator installed on Android Studio. Any ideas about what I need to do to enable it? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was opening the file from `build.gradle`.

[image]

Then I could see the play button successfully.

[image]